# Javascript adding/removing classes

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm working to create a responsive website using javascript/mootools. 
I have created two classes `desktop_tabs`, that holds functionality for the desktop version and `mobile_tabs`, which holds functionality for the mobile version. I also have a function `get_page_dims`, which returns the width of the window.

My function `run_check` is suppose to check the width and add/remove these classes based on the size. When resized it is adding the mobile version but not removing the desktop class. It's also not adding the desktop class properly to the larger version.

```
run_check: function () {
    current_width = this.get_page_dims(2);

    if (current_width <= 600 && this.options.mobile_flag === false) {
        this.options.desktop_flag = false;
        this.options.mobile_flag = true;

        $('services_nav').className = '';
        $('services_nav').removeClass(this.desktop_tabs);
        this.mobile_tabs (
            $('services_nav'),
            $('services_content'),
            0
        );
    }

  if (current_width > 600 && this.options.desktop_flag === false) {
        this.options.mobile_flag = false;
        this.options.desktop_flag = true;

        $('services_nav').className = '';
        $('services_nav').removeClass(this.mobile_tabs);
        this.desktop_tabs (
            $('services_nav'),
            $('services_content'),
            0
        );  
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: desktop_tabs and mobile_tabs are initiated classes that I am calling within this class in order to set the different functionalities

Comment: run check and the two classes are held in the same class. Hope that clears it up

Comment: How do you initialize `this.mobile_tabs` and `this.desktop_tabs`. I am not familiar with mootools but the calls `this.mobile_tabs (...)` and `this.desktop_tabs (...)` looks a bit weird. Any messages in the console?

Comment: what is `this.desktop_tabs`, it should be a `string`, not clear what you mean by "initiated classes"? are `this.mobile_tabs` and `this.desktop_tabs` a __[Class](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class)?__

Comment: mobile_tabs: function(nav_element, content_element, initialTab_option) { //do stuff }, this is above the run_check function. It is called/initiated when the width is a certain size (in code above).

Comment: And what you expect for behavior with `removeClass()`, just trying to understand what you want to do better.

Comment: both classes give the div certain attributes but I only want to display one at a time, hence removeClass

Comment: If you have a CSS class then `.removeClass()` expects a string, so you should use `.removeClass('desktop_tabs')`. If you mean `desktop_tabs` is a method then just run it, it's not related to `.removeClass()` method which is designed for CSS classes. Does this make sense?

Comment: Did you see my last comment?

Comment: Yes I'll try what you suggested. Thank You!